# check only direct childs without subchilds when parent checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If I check parent node all the childs are being checked but I want to check only child checkbox which does not have subchilds, when parent is checked.

I have created jsfiddle below, in which if we Check A1 only a2 should be checked. All other operation should be same.

```js
$('li :checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var $chk = $(this),
    $li = $chk.closest('li'),
    $ul, $parent;
  if ($li.has('ul')) {
    $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
  }
  do {

    $ul = $li.parent();
    $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
    if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
      $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
    } else {
      $parent.prop('checked', false)
    }
    if ($ul.get(0))
      if ($ul.find(':checkbox:checked').length !== 0)
        $parent.prop('checked', true)
    $chk = $parent;
    $li = $chk.closest('li');

  } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <li class='chkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='5'>A1
    <ul>
      <li class='chkbox'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='26'>a2
        <li class='chkbox'>
          <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='25'>a1
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox'>
              <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='27'>aaaaaa
              <li class='chkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='28'>abbbbbb
          </ul>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both">
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq4Ldr5c/)

Comment: Is there a question here?   You've described what you want and provided some random code that seems vaguely related.  Also the title and code don't match as it looks like your checkboxes will be in a `ul>li` so will not be direct children.  But impossible to tell what `A1` and `a2` are without HTML.  Can you provide details regarding exactly which part you are having difficulties with and/or why your code doesn't do what you want and/or why you can't make it do what you want.

Comment: I have given in jsfiddle thats why i didn't give html code in the question.

Comment: You could be more precise in your explanation, and it will probably force you to think more rigorously and maybe lead to a solution by yourself: a checkbox cannot have children elements. So you cannot have a parent checkbox too. Try to think with precision. Who is really parent and children?

Comment: Change `$li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)` to `$li.find('>ul>li>:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get only the direct descendants of `$li` instead of `$li.find(':checkbox')` which would return all descendants. Then you could filter the ones with no `ul` siblings.

e.g.

```
$li.find('> ul > li > :checkbox').filter(function(){
  return $(this).siblings('ul').length === 0;
}).prop('checked', this.checked);
```

It's also probably a good idea to close your `li` tags. It's quite hard to understand your `HTML` structure as it is.